# How to bring out a detail through Displacement

Tags: texturing, displacement

I am planning to model a large scale project for my design semester and due to the limited time frame I have, I want to get things done through quicker effective options. Since in this project I'll have to model each element, I need to provide a great deal of detail for one of them i.e. the Columns. This is a traditional Hindu architectural column

[image]

The problem is I don't have enough time to go through tutorials atm to model every bit of detail so I thought I could rely on the Displacement modifier to do the Job. I am using Knald to generate the required maps, and on its 3D Preview I see great and promising results.

[image][image]

However, when I try using these maps in Blender's node editor they are still quite flat. The displacement modifier gives me a weird result as all the faces have this linear length-wise bump, and the detail is seen only at the top and bottom faces.

[image][image]

Whats the best I could do to fix this? I'd definitely like a result as seen in Knalds 3D Preview.

Comment: You simply don't have enough geometry. Try to use MicroDisplacement while rendering, There are plenty of guides about it.

Comment: the above is right: displacement needs geometry (normal mapping fakes geometry)

Comment: When you say it needs more geometry, what does it actually mean? Do you refer to subdividing the object? or does it need to have more faces that is projected and extruded?

Comment: it is basically the same: you need more geometry on the mesh surface that needs to replicate a such complicated pattern... you could use subsurf levels (save file before), or as suggested, try microdisplacement (if using cycles). How many vertices are you using in the last image?

Comment: I have sub divided the cube quite a lot..and whether I sub-divide it by 10 or 50..I see the pattern only in the top and bottom face. I even tried increasing the no. of views of the subsurf modifier, but all it does is slows the system.